# Powershell to remove first 500 characters and last two characters

Tags: powershell

I have n number of text files in a folder. Each file will have only one line of text in it. I have to remove the first 500 characters and last two characters from each of the file in the folder.

How could this be done using Powershell?

Comment: How big are the files? Small enough to load into each fully in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Substring()` method to extract a substring from the line:

```sh
# Read single line from file
$line = Get-Content file.txt -TotalCount 1

# Extract a substring starting from index 500 until two characters before the end
$truncatedLine = $line.Substring(500, $line.Length - 502)

# Write line back to file
$truncatedLine |Set-Content file.txt -Force
```

To run against all txt files in a given folder, use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files, then process them one-by-one using `ForEach-Object`:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\path\to\folder -File -Filter *.txt |ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_ |Get-Content -TotalCount 1
    $truncatedLine = $line.Substring(500, $line.Length - 502)
    $truncatedLine |Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, take out the first 5 numbers and last 2.  Array indexes start at 0.

```
$string = '1234567890'
-join $string[5..($string.length-3)]

678
```